# Command to initialize Openshift router

Tags: openshift-origin

I followed the instructions here
https://hub.docker.com/r/openshift/origin/

To setup Openshift Origin with Centos 7 however there's no hint to actually make the `/console` accessible. Digging the internet I found that I need to setup a `router` first.

What is the command to initialize Openshift router?

Comment: Do you mean to deploy a router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console is started automatically - you do not need to use a router to access it.  The console listens on the same address and port as the API (defaults to the first IPv4 address, or the value of --master).  If you are accessing the master using port forwarding from a system that can't access that IP address you may also need to set --public-master=localhost when you start Openshift, which tells the console to generate links to localhost for your browser instead of the internal IP.

Comment: I deployed Openshift in a Rackspace CloudServer so the --public-master should be set to?